# cordova.InAppBrowser returns null url event '{type: "loadstop", url: null}'

Tags: google-chrome, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm running cordova for the browser: `cordova run browser`

I'm opening unsecured chrome browser in Ubuntu:

```
google-chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/temp_chrome_user_data_dir_for_cordova --disable-web-security --no-referrers
```

But `loadstop` event returns empty url: `{type: "loadstop", url: null}`

(Also, I'm injecting and using cordova from an iframe)

---

edits:

- `--no-referrers` flag doesn't affect the event return
- can't test it in Firefox with `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy=false` because don't let me inject cordova

> SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "cordova" on cross-origin object

Answer (score 0):

Seems related to this chrome bug: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1951

The solution for me was:

> Add the --disable-site-isolation-trials argument to chrome